# Laravel back() doesn't use _previous

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to use

```
return back();
```

In one of my controllers however it always seems to return back to the home page if I however use

```
return Redirect::to($request->session->get('_previous')['url']);
```

It does work so it seems that for some reason the back() function isn't grabbing _previous correctly. Any way to fix this? I've noticed it in other controllers as well.